# How to extract only certain dependencies using StanfordNLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I need to take out only agent relationships in every sentence using StanfordNLP? I tried using
sentence.get(AbgeneAnnotation.class); where sentence is an instance of Sentence, I din't get any output?

Is there any other way to do so?